# Is there a function within gtsummary to add the R2, N, and F-statistic to an output table which includes multiple models?

Tags: r, regression, gtsummary, gt

I'm using `tbl_merge` to add several regression models together and present them in a single table, but would ideally like to be able to present the R2, F-statistic, and N for each model at the bottom of the table, as you can do for the case of a single model with `add_glance_source_note`. Is there an easy way to do this?

Comment: Unfortunately, not at the moment. It's something that is planned, but we don't have a timeline for it yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the function `add_glance_table()` to append the additional statistics to the table. Example below!

```r
library(gtsummary)
packageVersion("gtsummary")
#> [1] '1.4.0'

tbl1 <-
  lm(marker ~ age + grade, trial) %>% 
  tbl_regression() %>%
  add_glance_table(include = c(nobs, r.squared))

tbl2 <- tbl_merge(list(tbl1, tbl1))
```

[image]
<sup>Created on 2021-04-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>